# Google Calendar API - Non OAuth Authentication

Tags: authentication, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to build a script that runs on a dedicated server to access Google Calendar API.  This script should be able to have access to our accounts Google Calendar, say User X, and all other calendars that User X has access to.  I do not need to run this via a web browser and then have access to other peoples (outside our org) calendars.  This needs to run on a server and only have access to our organization (G Suite) calendars and users in our G-Suite account.  Basically I am wanting to do the following things:

1. Create calendars, and give access to other org (G Suite) members
2. Create/modify events in these calendars
3. Send notifications about events

From looking at the Google Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth), it looks like the only way to access is through OAuth authentication, which I do not need at all, as this will be running on a dedicated server through a script.

Is there a way to do this?  Am I missing something in the API documentation?  This seems weird that I would not be able to access our own Calendar data through a server process and valid/restricted API key (which I have set up).

Comment: You would need to create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) in GCP to allow server-to-server authentication. It still uses OAuth 2.0, which cannot be removed, but at least you would not need to authenticate manually for every user.

Answer (score 1):

Api keys only give you access to public data not private user data.

What you will need to do is set up service account authentication and have your google workspace admin set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth#perform-google-workspace-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority) on the service account. This will give the service account the abilities to preform actions on behalf of the user who owns these calendars.